# Plotting line graph over scatter graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I am aware of how to plot a line graph on top of scatter plot of the same data but is there a way to bring the line graph forward so it sits on top of the markers rather than behind?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=0.1,yerr=0.1, fmt="x",markersize=5, color = "orange")
plt.plot(x,y)
```

This code outputs a scatter graph with a line graph behind it. When you increase the number of data points it becomes harder to see the line behind them all. Other than decreasing the marker size can I bring the line on top of all the points?

Comment: Could you please include imports, x1, and y1 so it is a complete post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are intending to draw things at different levels of z-order on the screen. This is done like such:

```
plt.plot(x,y, zorder=10)
```

Note 10 is arbitrarily large and this will likely plot on top of your legend too, so you may need to adjust it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `barsabove=True`. This places the error bars above the markers and the line is displayed on the top of error bars and markers. To highlight this effect, I am using a thick error bar. As you can see, the blue line lies above the error bars and markers. Use `barsabove=False` (default value) to see the difference.

```
x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr=0.1,yerr=0.1, linewidth=10, fmt="x",markersize=5, color = "orange", barsabove=True)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]